# Me and My Gang, Again

Tags: riddle, word

This puzzle was inspired by [Me and My Gang](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13257/me-and-my-gang). I really enjoyed that puzzle, and hope that this one is as challenging and fun. I think it might be a bit easier than [Me and My Gang](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13257/me-and-my-gang), but we'll see.

> Before any of my friends came, I was used a lot.
>
> A friend came to visit me, allowing us to go to all sorts of places.
>
> A third joined us, and the world truly enjoyed us regularly.
>
> The fourth addition to our group channeled us to cooler places.
>
> Our fifth member allowed us to move faster than any jet,
>
> but the sixth made us a menace to those around us.
>
> Thankfully, the seventh allowed us to relax and be entertained.
>
> The eighth transformed us into a useful medical device.

**Who am I and who are my friends? What did we become?**

Comment: Then the ninth got us all really wound up. But finally, our tenth brought us all back together again.

Comment: I intended ratcheted for 9, but well done. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it!

*Before any of my friends came, I was used a lot.*

> A (the most common single-letter word in English).

*A friend came to visit me, allowing us to go to all sorts of places.*

> AT (you can be *at* all sorts of places) - thanks pacoverflow!

*A third joined us, and the world truly enjoyed us regularly.*

> TEA (many people all over the world enjoy tea regularly) - thanks again pacoverflow!

*The fourth addition to our group channeled us to cooler places.*

> HEAT (seems a bit counter-intuitive, but heat does move towards where it's cooler).

*Our fifth member allowed us to move faster than any jet,*

> EARTH (the speed of the Earth's rotation is probably faster than a jet).

*but the sixth made us a menace to those around us.*

> THREAT.

*Thankfully, the seventh allowed us to relax and be entertained.*

> THEATRE / THEATER.

*The eighth transformed us into a useful medical device.*

> CATHETER.

Comment: @EngineerToast Goddammit, a useless upvote :-P

Comment: It's not useless if it contributes to a badge. There's more to life than just points. For instance, there are other kinds of points.

Comment: @EngineerToast I spot a fellow addict - and love the update to your profile page! ;-)

Comment: Well done (assuming it's right). I'd got as far as THREAT/THEATRE but didn't get to EARTH or HEAT...

Comment: I thought about Catheter but I thought it was like the other one where it was all different letters :P

Comment: I don't know about this EA answer for the second clue.  Maybe AT instead?  Also I like TEA for the third clue.  Good job on the rest! +1 :)

Comment: And just pointing out, Earth isn't moving faster than any jet since the jet is moving inside earth's atmosphere in relativity to earth's speed,   but I'm just being picky because no one likes my lazer eyed lizard :P

Comment: @pacoverflow Yes, you are correct about TEA being the intended 3rd word, and I think it fits the clue a little better too.

Comment: @Spacemonkey The earth orbits the sun at 6,660 miles per hour. The Lockheed SR-71 Blackbird (a manned jet) can go 2,193 miles per hour, relative to the Earth. But technically you are correct, since the jet is moving inside the atmosphere, as you said. So, technically, by that perspective, the jet could be moving faster in certain circumstances. However, adjusting speeds for our planes, cars, etc for that would be quite a feat, and would confuse everything, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: @JLee OK, I've changed EAT to TEA. Are A and AT correct for the first two?

Answer (score 2):

I hate these puzzles ...    I can't get them out of my mind and they take so long before they are solved... -_-    so annoying :P

Here's my try. have fun googling what they are if you don't know. Because I'm evil too. (mwahahahahaha)

```
Before any of my friends came, I was used a lot.
```

> A

```
A friend came to visit me, allowing us to go to all sorts of places.
```

> ra/ad?  :: or EA (company)

```
A third joined us, and the world truly enjoyed us regularly.
```

> Rad  or Ale

```
The fourth addition to our group channeled us to cooler places.
```

> arid/radz or real/earl/zale????????

```
Our fifth member allowed us to move faster than any jet,
```

> Z-RAID or Lazer

```
but the sixth made us a menace to those around us.
```

> Lizard or Azriel

```
Thankfully, the seventh allowed us to relax and be entertained.
```

> Zeliard

```
The eighth transformed us into a useful medical device.
```

> Dialyzer

Comment: I've never heard half these words. The OP said it was meant to be easy!

Comment: lol, the only one that isn't really a word is lazer, its a disambiguation of laser ... i think. Azriel is another name used for Azrael (angel of death), zeliard is an old nec game - i have no clue what a dialyzer is but its a medical thingy

Comment: Confession: I solved it by just going to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Medical_equipment) Wikipedia page and taking the first 8-letter word I found!

Comment: Hey I did the same, i had 6 8 letter words for medical terms: Catheter, Dialyzer, Canister, Cerclage, Software, Surgical - I picked Dialyzer, it was fancier xD

Comment: @randal'thor OK, thank you for the info. Next time I will try not to include a hint that allows for that type of shortcut. Although it was still a great solve.

Comment: @JLee ,  now I want to find that stupid game and try it out xD   it doesnt look that bad for a nec game :P

Comment: @Spacemonkey Try the free download here: http://www.abandonia.com/en/downloadgame/957  (beware of installing other programs when it installs. I have never downloaded from this site). Let me know how it is.